# using pyodbc in Azure webjobs

Tags: azure

importing pyodbc fails with following error message

```
[05/10/2015 11:29:53 > 43b068: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: ERR ]   File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: ERR ]     import pyodbc
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: ERR ] ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[05/10/2015 11:30:10 > 43b068: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PyODBC in its 32 bits verison and everything will work :)